# multiple bulk email update 5.10.3

Tags: contacts, email, xdebug

We have updated our CiviCRM to the 5.10.3 but now we have trouble with bulk email.

The checkbox buttons behave like a radio button. 
So we can not have more the one bulk email address (not really useful)

For old contact the data are correct but we can not change it.

No one has this trouble? 
No one has an idea to resolve it?

Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

You must enable the ‘Enable multiple bulk email address for a contact’ option from CiviMail component settings.

Administer > CiviMail > CiviMail component settings

/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid it's already the case: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUx3u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUx3u.png)

Comment: Have you tried clearing CiviCRM cache? –

Administer > System Settings > Cleanup caches and update paths.

It’s definitely not a bug as I have it working as expected on a 5.10.3 environment.
(Have added a screenshot)

Comment: I did and it didn't change anything. It's reassuring that it's not a bug but I can definitely reproduce the issue. I even have a 5.10.4 installation with the same config and environment that experiences the very same behaviour